# don't download video again if I close the app and open again if it's already downloaded before iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am developing an app where I need to download a video and then perform some editing on it.So, I am downloading a video using **NSURLSession** and when I Have downloaded it,I close the app and then open it again.Now instead of using that downloaded video,I need to check if its already downloaded and then get the URL.Here is the code that I have been using:

```
    -(void)startDownloadingWithURLString:(NSString*)urlString{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

  task = [self.urlSession downloadTaskWithURL:url];
  [task resume];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSession delagate methods

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *fileManager_ = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.mp4"]];

if([fileManager_ fileExistsAtPath:[location path]]){

    [fileManager_ replaceItemAtURL:url withItemAtURL:location backupItemName:nil options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:nil];
    _videoURLPath = url;
}
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([url path
                                     ], nil, nil, nil);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
self.progressView_.progress = 0.0;

});
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

    NSLog(@"%f",(double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.progressView_.progress = (double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

});
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{

[KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Download complete"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_videoURLPath.path]];

[AppHelper saveToUserDefaults:_videoURLPath.path withKey:@"videoURL"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    SAEditUploadViewController *editVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SAEditUploadViewController"];

    editVC.videoPathData = data;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editVC animated:YES];

});
}
```